# Using Custom Packages Causes Circular Dependency

Tags: vhdl, circular-dependency, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I'm trying to declare an unsigned array in a package so that I can use the same type of array across all of my components. I declared it in the top-level component first, and then used the work library and `use` command to call on the package in each component. I receive a warning that says

> WARNING:ProjectMgmt:454 - File circular dependency detected using rule:  define-before-use.

I also receive an error that says

> Line 27: Cannot find `<test2>` in library `<work>`. Please ensure that the library was compiled, and that a library and a use clause are present in the VHDL file.

Why is there circular dependency, and am I creating and using the package correctly?

Top-Level Component

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

package pkg is
  type array_unsigned is array (99 downto 0) of UNSIGNED(7 downto 0);
end package;

package body pkg is
end package body;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
library work;
use work.pkg.ALL;

entity test1 is
end test1;

architecture Behavioral of test1 is
    signal input : array_unsigned;
begin
sub: entity work.test2(Behavioral)
    port map(input=>input);
end Behavioral;
```

Lower-level Component

```
library IEEE;
library work;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use work.pkg.ALL;

entity test2 is
    Port (input : in array_unsigned);
end test2;

architecture Behavioral of test2 is

begin


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: What tool are you using? Your code compiles fine in ModelSim, having changed the `test1` output port to an input. Also, you don't have to declare the `work` library.

Comment: It works for me on ModelSim as well, but it cannot be synthesized in ISE Project Navigator.

Comment: Try Project > Cleanup project files. Also, try removing your `library work;` lines, perhaps these are confusing it.

Comment: I tried both, but got the same results.

Comment: Perhaps it doesn't like your package being in the same file as `test1`; try putting the package in it's own file (I think this would be more conventional anyway). If that doesn't work then I'm not sure sorry!

Comment: Thanks! Putting it in its own file worked.

Comment: Should I put this as an answer?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not that the first file contains both `pkg` package and `test1` entity. This is fine and not a circular dependency. Many, including myself, might consider it a bad practice though. The real problem is that `test1` instantiates `test2` entity from a separate file which also uses `pkg`. Thus the circular dependency where `test2` depends on `pkg` but the file containing `pkg` and `test1` depends on `test2` because it was instantiated there.

Modelsim supports compiling only specific design units within a file so it might be able to handle the situation.

Answer (score 1):

Your package `pkg` appears to be defined in the same file as entity `test1`, which itself `use`s this package. Although I don't see this as strictly wrong, it looks like ISE has spotted that it needs to compile your first file (to compile the package), before it can compile the same file to compile the entity `test1`, and produced an error. In reality, if it simply went ahead and compiled the file, everything would be OK.

By moving the package to its own file, this apparent self dependency is removed.

Comment: Moving the package to its own file solves the problem but your analysis of the problem is wrong. The circular dependency is between the file containing test1 and pkg and the file containing test2. This is because the first file requires test2 since it is instantiated there while the second file requires pkg.

Comment: Oh right, yes I suppose that does make more sense. Thanks!